# What about this question is not constructive?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474113/why-does-microsoft-recommend-against-empty-interfaces

This question is closed, there is no reason to be closed. Since it was closed it has received over 500 views and 14+ upvotes on the question alone. It is obviously a question that many member of our community have encountered.

I understand the mods need to moderate but closing this question is obviously not helping our community.

Personally I don't really care if the mods don't like my question, I don't answer/ask questions here for the mods. I do it for the community and I think they should have some kind of weight in how a question is handled.

Clicking the re-open button is useless, as it has been ignored time after time. 
Kind of frustrating ...

Comment: By bringing it up on Meta you're up to 4/5 people voting to re-open. It may be close again immediately afterwards for the same reason though... [Being closed, doesn't mean it'll be deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Comment: Why are you just now bringing it up almost a year later?

Comment: Because I have tried to find other ways to get the question re-opened unsuccessfully

Comment: Because votes on meta are different. [Meta-FAQ#vote-differences]

Comment: Why do you need the question opened again?  Are the existing answers insufficient?  If you feel the question hasn't been adequately answered (and it manages to reopen), post a bounty.

Comment: Although this is tagged `specific-question`, it does not argue the specific merits of your linked question.  If you can revise the post to propose the specific merits of *that* question and it's benefit to the community and/or the internet (14 upvotes and 500 views is *nothing*, if anything, it's deletion-fodder) then we can reopen *this* question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey might this question make more sense on programmers.se? I don't think it's a bad question, it's just in the wrong place (should be on a "conceptual whiteboard")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it's not constructive. Read the paragraph below the "Closed as not constructive" box:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. See the FAQ for guidance on how to improve it.

There is no definitive answer to this question.  Everyone may have an opinion for why this is recommended.  Stack Overflow is for Q&A not discussions.

> Personally I don't really care if the mods don't like my question...

Mods didn't close this question.  It was closed by a quorum of five 3000+ rep community members, just like yourself.